# Question about curly-curly '{{ }}' use in rlang 4.0

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to use map() to save a list of objects in compressed format files individually (as .rds files). The code first reads all the objects and memory, filters them to include only the types of objects of interest and stores the result as a list. The function then should go ahead and take the objects one at a time and save the results in rds format. But, I clearly have not understood the new article about the {{ syntax. The result I've put in the reprex is the latest attempt. Can someone directly help or send me to another resource (other than the rlang 0.4 post on the tidyverse site) that explains how to use curly-curly in a manner even I can understand. I'm trying to switch to a more functional approach in my research and help here will be greatly appreciated. The code is below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, as_function, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl,
#>     flatten_int, flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, invoke, list_along,
#>     modify, prepend, splice

## Prepare the vector of object names
objs_fail <- enframe(objects(), name = NULL) %>% 
   filter(str_sub(value, 1,3) %in% c("dif", "fil", "met", "myD", "tss")) 
objs_fail <- as.list(objs_fail$value)
type <- "vfail"

## function to take the objects and store them into individual compressed files
save_the_files <- function(objs, type) {
   map({{objs}}, saveRDS(.data[[obj]], 
                         paste0("./cg_", type, "/", .data[[obj]], "_", type, ".rds")))
}
```

Created on 2019-07-14 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

The function would be called by a call like

```
save_the_files(objs_fail, "vfail")
```

and the individual objects in the list would be strings like "diffAnn"

Thanks for the help.

Jim Hunter

Comment: What is in `objs_fail`?  Strings?  (When I run your code I just get an empty list.)  Does your function work if you pass `objs` directly to `map()` without the curly-curly?  Also, the code for your function in `map()` looks off to me (you have no `~` or anonymous function); does the current `map()` code work outside your function?

Comment: Lionel Henry (@lionel) responded to my question on RStudio Community in a way that I hope solves it. https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-rlang-curly-curly/35281. To answer your question objs_fail is a list of strings and I too got an empty list as the best result I managed. No, the direct pass of objs to map() gets a NULL result. Part of Lionel's answer also includes the ~ that I had forgotten. And, finally, I hadn't tried the map() outside the function. I should have.